# Error while installing VIM package in R-2.15.3

Tags: r, install.packages

i am new to this software. i dont have any technical background. I am installing VIM package in R-2.15.3. I am getting the below error while running library command.

> install.packages("VIM")
>   Installing package(s) into ‘C:/Users/Jatin/Documents/R/win-library/2.15’
>   (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
>   also installing the dependency ‘e1071’

trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/2.15/e1071_1.6-1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 515357 bytes (503 Kb)
opened URL
downloaded 503 Kb

trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/2.15/VIM_4.0.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1056566 bytes (1.0 Mb)
opened URL
downloaded 1.0 Mb

package ‘e1071’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to move temporary installation ‘C:\Users\Jatin\Documents\R\win-library\2.15\file1d8452ba3ff5\e1071’ to ‘C:\Users\Jatin\Documents\R\win-library\2.15\e1071’
package ‘VIM’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\Jatin\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpusJxQN\downloaded_packages

> library(VIM)
>   Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths())) : 
>     there is no package called ‘e1071’
>   Error: package/namespace load failed for ‘VIM’

please help me on this.